# Thunar shows a non-existent directory

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-mate, filemanager

I use Thunar as my file manager.

I once had a Python directory but it was deleted.

But Thunar is still displaying it.

Caja does not show that directory.

How can I fix the issue with Thunar?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/g0OdIr2]

When I click on the Python directory, I get this

[image: https://imgur.com/a/vBOKzIH]

Comment: Have you tried to reload by doing View -> Reload or Ctrl+R?

Comment: @Terrance Yes, I tried reload.

Comment: Is there a way you can maybe do a screenshot of what you are seeing for us?  I am wondering if it might be a hidden directory that is showing up because the show Hidden Files might be enabled.  Ctrl+h can enable or disable showing hidden files.  But I am not seeing anything about Thunar caching directories, only thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

From

https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=17239

That looks like a bookmark/shortcut, not an actual folder. Right-click it and select the "Remove Shortcut" option.